# How to replace a character within a string with regex?

Tags: javascript, regex, string, replace, match

I have a string:

```
let y = ".1875 X 7.00 X 8.800";
```

I would like to return this as an array of 3 numbers: 0.1875, 7.00, 8.800

I need to convert .1875 into 0.1875, however you can't just target the first character because what if the string is like so:

```
let x = "7.00 X .1875 X 8.800";

or another difficult example

let y = ".50" x 1.25" x 7.125" will make one part"
```

This is my attempt so far:

```
let numbers = x.match(/(\d*\.)?\d+/g)
numbers.map(n => parseFloat(n))


var thickness = numbers[0]
var width = numbers[1]
var length = numbers[2]


if(thickness.charAt(0) == '.'){

    let stringA = numbers[0].match(/^(\.)/g)
    let stringB = "0"

    thickness.replace(stringA, stringB)
    console.log(thickness)}

else {
     alert('failure');
}
```

I can't seem to replace the . in .1875 to 0.1875, any help much appreciated!

Comment: `let y = ".50" x 1.25" x 7.125" will make one part"` isn't valid JavaScript.

Comment: @test3r123 ... The OP actually does not want _"... to return this as an array of 3 numbers: `0.1875`, `7.00`, `8.800`"_ but _as an array of 3 stringified numbers with a sanitized/normalized number format `"0.1875"`, `"7.00"`, `"8.800"`.

Comment: @PeterSeliger test3r123 is the OP. You're currently telling the OP what they want. And since the OP accepted an answer that produces numbers, I guess they want numbers.

Comment: @jabaa ... almost ... The OP actually her/himself came up with this requirement, since the OP states ... _"I would like to return this as an array of 3 numbers: 0.1875, 7.00, 8.800"_ ... A number type will never look like this the trailing zeros are omitted ... `0.1875, 7, 8.8`. Only a string value can cover the OP's format requirement. The audience seems to think alike since the approaches which coerce the result into a number type are not high voted.

Comment: @PeterSeliger I completely understand what you mean, but the other answer is accepted.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Here is one way to do so using regex:

```js
let x = "7.00 X .1875 X 8.800";

const pattern = /\d*\.?\d+/g;

const numbers = [...x.matchAll(pattern)].map(Number);
console.log(numbers);
```

---

- `\d*`: Matches any digit between 0 and unlimited times, as much as possible.
- `\.?`: Optionally matches `.`.
- `\d+`: Matches any digit between 1 and unlimited times, as much as possible.

Answer (score 0):

From the above comment ...

> The OP actually does not want *"... to return this as an array of 3 numbers: `0.1875`, `7.00`, `8.800`"* but *as an array of 3 stringified numbers with a sanitized/normalized number format `"0.1875"`, `"7.00"`, `"8.800"`*.

A possible approach was the combination of

- fetching ... [`/(?<!\d)(?:\d*\.)?\d+/g`](https://regex101.com/r/gxZm0u/1) ... and ...
- normalizing ... `.replace(/^\./, '0$&')` ... valid number formats.

```js
const sampleData = `
  .1875 X 7.00 X 8.800 
  7.00 X .1875 X 8.800 
  .50" x 1.25" x 7.125" will make one part

  .1875 X 7.00 X 8.800 X 456 X 13.45.56.343.343.
`;

// see ... [(?<!\d)(?:\d*\.)?\d+]
const regXValidNumber = /(?<!\d)(?:\d*\.)?\d+/g;

console.log(
  sampleData
    // retrieving the array of
    // valid stringified numbers.
    .match(regXValidNumber)
);
console.log(
  sampleData
    // retrieving the array of
    // valid stringified numbers.
    .match(regXValidNumber)
    // normalizing the number format.
    .map(str => str.replace(/^\./, '0$&'))
);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```